# Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/***] not found before reading the properties file

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, jndi

Good Mornig.

I have an application in tomcat 8, java 1.7, Spring 3.2.2 and primefaces 5.0. When the application starts, it shows the next debug message in console:

> Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/etl.csv.token]
>   localhost-startStop-1: org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate
>   Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/etl.csv.token] not found

But the key isn't in the JNDI context. It is in a properties file. The application works fine and takes the property from the properties file, but i can't understand why spring is trying to find the property in the JNDI context

The properties file is like this:

```
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.initialSize=3
database.maxActive=15
database.maxIdle=10
database.minIdle=3
database.maxWait=10000
etl.csv.token=,
```

And its properties are used like this:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${database.initialSize}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${database.maxActive}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${database.maxIdle}" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="${database.maxWait}" />
        <property name="minIdle" value="${database.minIdle}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" />
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

For all properties, the behaviour is the same. I would like that message does not appear

Sorry for the english, is not my native language

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: Disable debug logging. Spring will consult all the available `PropertySource`s that are available one of them is the `JndiPropertySource` which, as the name implies, does a lookup in the JNDI. The message you aer seeing is logged at debug level if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You are right, is logging in debug mode. I thought that there was a way to disable the validation, not only disabling the log. thx